# How to create a timer on python

Tags: python

I am creating a code that requires the program to time how long it runs for and then displays the time. it is basically a timer that runs in the background and I can call upon it to display how long the code has been running for. How do I do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You record the start time, then later on calculate the difference between that start time and the current time.

Due to platform differences, for precision you want to use the [`timeit.default_timer` callable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer):

```
from timeit import default_timer

start = default_timer()

# do stuff

duration = default_timer() - start
```

This gives you a wall-clock time duration in seconds as a floating point value.

Demo:

```
>>> from timeit import default_timer
>>> start = default_timer()
>>> # Martijn reads another post somewhere
... 
>>> print default_timer() - start
19.1996181011
```

Answer (score 6):

This is easy in python

```
import time
start_time=time.time()
#do something
end_time=time.time()-start_time
```

The resultant `end_time` will be in seconds

Answer (score 0):

I have done this, This may help you

```
from timeit import default_timer

timerPool = {}
TIMER_RUNNING = 1
TIMER_STOPPED = 0
TIMER_IDLE = 2


"""
Initilialize the timer like below if any new timer to be added
"""
"""
required initialization for "eightSecTimer_Id" timer
"""
timerPool['eightSecTimer_Id'] = {}
timerPool['eightSecTimer_Id']['state'] = TIMER_IDLE
timerPool['eightSecTimer_Id']['start'] = 0
timerPool['eightSecTimer_Id']['duration'] = 0
timerPool['eightSecTimer_Id']['time'] = 0

"""
required initialization for "fiveSecTimer_Id" timer
"""
timerPool['fiveSecTimer_Id'] = {}
timerPool['fiveSecTimer_Id']['state'] = TIMER_IDLE
timerPool['fiveSecTimer_Id']['start'] = 0
timerPool['fiveSecTimer_Id']['duration'] = 0
timerPool['fiveSecTimer_Id']['time'] = 0

"""
Interface to start the timer
"""
def StartTimer(Id,time):
    timerPool[Id]['time'] = time
    timerPool[Id]
    if (timerPool[Id]['state'] == TIMER_IDLE) or (timerPool[Id]['state'] == TIMER_STOPPED):
        timerPool[Id]['start'] = default_timer()
        timerPool[Id]['state'] = TIMER_RUNNING
    return timerPool[Id]['state']

"""
Interface to get the timer status.
Return "TIMER_STOPPED" when timer completed
Return "TIMER_IDLE" after timer completed on consecutive call of this function
"""

def GetTimerState(Id):
    time = timerPool[Id]['time']
    if timerPool[Id]['state'] == TIMER_RUNNING:
        timerPool[Id]['duration'] = default_timer() - timerPool[Id]['start']
    else:
        None
    if timerPool[Id]['state'] == TIMER_STOPPED:
        timerPool[Id]['state'] = TIMER_IDLE

    if  timerPool[Id]['duration'] >= time:
        timerPool[Id]['state'] = TIMER_STOPPED
        timerPool[Id]['duration'] = 0
    return timerPool[Id]['state'] 

"""
Below is how to use.
"""
StartTimer('fiveSecTimer_Id',5)
StartTimer('eightSecTimer_Id',8)

while True:
    if GetTimerState('fiveSecTimer_Id') == TIMER_STOPPED:
        print "5 sec Timer Stopped"
    if GetTimerState('eightSecTimer_Id') == TIMER_STOPPED:
        print "8 sec Timer Stopped"        
    sleep (.5)
```

Comment: Instead of nested dictionaries, why not use custom classes? It'd make the code a lot more readable.

Comment: What could possibly be the purpose of this code?