# Python Windows get key press length and time between each press

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a button recorder for a game I'm working on, but it requires timings (around 100 or so)

I need a program that can record when I press the spacebar in another program, for how long it's held down for (`heldtime`), and the time in between the next press in milliseconds (`waittime`). (formatted as `jump(heldtime, waittime`)) Pressing the Z key stops the recording.

I am using Python 2.7

If any more information is needed, I will edit to add it upon request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to learn how to set a timer: 
[How to create a timer on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211188/how-to-create-a-timer-on-python)

And use this to learn how to create events to listen for the spacebar being pressed (provided you're using the Tkinter module to write your code):
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Here is what that might look like put together:

```
from timeit import default_timer
from Tkinter import *

key_pressed = False
last_start = 0
heldtime_array = []

def start_stop_timer():
    if key_pressed == False:
       last_start = default_timer()
       key_pressed = True
    else:
        heldtime_array[len(heldtime_array)] = default_timer() - last_start

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
# This will work with any key. See above link for specific keys.
frame.bind("<Key>", start_stop_timer)
frame.pack()

# Do other customisation/setup of your window here.

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I cant get this one to work, probably because of Tkinter using a window, when I'm trying to record keyboard presses in another window :/

Comment: @whamer100 call the .bind method on whatever window is active when you want to listen for the keypress event.

Comment: @whamer100 I've added an array, heldtime_array, which will have all your heldtime durations in it. This should enable you to access the most recent and all historic heldtimes anywhere in the program. Hope this helps!