# Record momentum consecutively when each key is pressed in a count timer while executing keylogger.py

Tags: python, timer, keylogger, pynput

I have the following code-file `keylogger.py` below to detect a specific key being pressed and saving to `log.txt` file.
I want to add to this python code a timer that starts when the code starts to run, I also want this part of the code to save the exact moment the `keys` were pressed starting with the start of the file and save this information in the `log.txt` file or another separate file (would need to use `with open` and `f.write` I think). Several timekeeping ideas I found in [How to create a timer on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211188/how-to-create-a-timer-on-python) and https://pythonhow.com/measure-execution-time-python-code/.

**So my log.txt would be something like**

**log.py**

```
RLLR     #this line would already be produced by keylogger.py

R: 0.2s
L:0.24s
L:1.34s
R:2.5s
```

**keylogger.py**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key

#set log file location
logFile = "/home/diego/log.txt"



def writeLog(key):
    translate_keys = {
        Key.right: "R",
        Key.left: "L",
    }
    if key in translate_keys:
        with open(logFile, "a") as f:
            f.write(translate_keys[key])

with Listener(on_press=writeLog) as l:
    l.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using separate files would be the simplest solution I think:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key
import time

#set log file location for keys pressed
keysLogFile = "/home/diego/keys_log.txt"

#set log file location for keys timestamps
timestampsLogFile = "/home/diego/ts_log.txt"

#store start timestamp
startTime = time.time()


def writeLog(key):
    translate_keys = {
        Key.right: "R",
        Key.left: "L",
    }
    if key in translate_keys:
        currentTime = time.time() - startTime
        with open(keysLogFile, "a") as f:
            f.write(translate_keys[key])
        with open(timestampsLogFile, "a") as f:
            f.write(translate_keys[key] + ": " + str(currentTime) + "s\n")

with Listener(on_press=writeLog) as l:
    l.join()
```

This would give you two separate files:

**keys_log.txt**

```
RLLR
```

**ts_log.txt**

```
R: 0.2s
L: 0.24s
L: 1.34s
R: 2.5s
```